# All bash commands lost after sourcing bash_profile after osx upgrade

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I recently upgraded my osx to os x el capitan. I noticed that `subl` command was missing so I tried adding the path to my bash_profile. It didn't work out so I removed it and then do a `source ~/.bash_profile` and now all of my bash commands are gone.

Here is my bash_profile file

```
export $PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

##
# Your previous /Users/judyngai/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/judyngai/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-06-27_at_16:30:58
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-06-27_at_16:30:58: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$path
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH


export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
:q!
```

and when I do `export $PATH`

I am getting this

`` 31-34-238:bin judyngai$ export $PATH
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:': not a valid identifier ``

I cd into all of the directories that its getting searched through `/usr/local/bin`, `/bin`, `/usr/local/bin` etc. and saw all of the commands in there.

and this

```
31-34-238:~ judyngai$ source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: export: `/Users/judyngai/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier
env: bash: No such file or directory
-bash: :q!: command not found
```

I actually think my bash_profile is fine so what is wrong? Rbenv and macport both look fine.

Comment: Lose the `$` in `export $PATH`, i.e. make it just `export PATH=...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is destroying your path: `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$path` -- variables are case sensitive.

However, this error

```
-bash: export:`/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:': not a valid identifier
```

Indicates you probably have this in your bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$path       # PATH=/usr/local/sbin:
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH        # PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
export $PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
# .....^
```

Where you are *substituting* the variable on the left-hand side instead of providing the variable *name*.

You export a variable (name), not a variable's value.